# How do I extract a value from inside of a formatted string?

Tags: c#, parsing, input

I got a string array and values are as follows

```
sNames[0] = "Root | [<root>] | [ID = 1]";
sNames[1] = "Planning | [Root] | [ID = 2]";
```

From this I would like to just extract ID value .. 1,2..

for now am do this as :

```
foreach (var s in sNames)
{
  int id = Convert.ToInt32(s.Split('|')[2].Split('=')[1].Substring(1,1));
  ...
}
```

Is there some other good way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regex to find the ID (the Match() part may not be 100% correct -- exercise left to the reader).

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\[ID = (?<id>[0-9]+)\]");
var ids = sNames.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(regex.Match(s).Groups["id"].Value));
```

Comment: Remember, this won't work under .NET 2.0 or 3.0 due to requiring Linq!

Comment: Then don't use Linq.  Linq isn't the important bit here.

Comment: Is the "<id>" part standard? I've never seen it.

Comment: That syntax ("<id>") allows you to name the group and exists in PCRE regex syntax.  .NET Regex allows you to do "(?<groupName>.*)" or "(?'groupname'.*)".  The latter is not compatible with other Regex libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex...

```
// using System.Text.RegularExpressions
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\[ID\s*=\s*(\d+)\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (var s in sNames)
{
  Match m = rx.Match(s);
  if (!m.Success) continue; // Couldn't find ID.
  int id = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].ToString());
  // ...
}
```

But [now you have two problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247).  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for regular expressions.  This will match all strings with the pattern of "ID = [some number]"

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...

foreach(string s in sNames) {
  Match m = Regex.Match("ID = ([0-9]+)");
  if(m.Success) {
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions is the "easiest". With the caveat of course that there's a huge learning curve for regex.

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\[ID\s*=\s*(?<id>\d+)\]");
Match m = rx.Match(str);
string id = m.Groups["id"].Value;
```